# Generating a python file

Tags: python, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm havin issues with python (Sorry for my personal feelings before.. :P).

I have a txt file, it contains a custom language and I have to translate it to a working python code.

The input:

```
import sys  

n = int(sys.argv[1]) ;;print "Beginning of the program!"

LOOP i in range(1,n) {print "The number:";;print i}

BRANCH n < 5 {print n ;;print "less than 5"}
```

The wanted output looks exactly like this:

```
import sys  

n = int(sys.argv[1])   
print "Beginning of the program!"

for i in range(1,n) :  
    print "The number:"  
    print i  

if n < 5 :  
    print n   
    print "less than 5"
```

The name of the input file is read from parameter. The out file is out.py. In case of a wrong parameter, it gives an error message. The ;; means a new line.

When I tried to do it, I made an array, I read all the lines into it, split by " ". Then I wanted to strip it from the marks I don't need. I made 2 loops, one for the lines, one for the words. So then I started to replace the things. Everything went fine until it came to the } mark. It finds it, but it can not replace or strip it. I have no more idea what to do.

My code (it's messy and I don't have the write to file at the moment):

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
#g = open('out.py', 'w')
allWords = map(lambda l: l.split(" "), f.readlines())
for i in range(len(allWords)):
    vanfor = -1
    vanif = -1
    for j in range(len(allWords[i])):
        a=allWords[i][j]
        a=a.replace(";;","\n")
        a=a.replace("CIKLUS","for")
        a=a.replace("ELAGAZAS","if")
        if a == "for":
            allWords[i][j+3] = str(allWords[i][j+3])+" :\n"
        if a == "if":
            allWords[i][j+3] = str(allWords[i][j+3])+" :\n"
        zarojel=a.find('}')
        if zarojel>-1:
            a=a.rstrip('}')
        a=a.replace("}","")
        a=a.replace("{","")
        if vanfor == -1:
            vanfor=a.find("for")
        if vanif == -1:
            vanif=a.find("if")
        if (vanfor > -1) or (vanif > -1):
            a=a.replace("print","   print")
        if j != (len(allWords[i]))-1:
            allWords[i][j]=a+" "
        print allWords[i][j],
```

Could someone help me, please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. You haven't posted your Python code, other than your desired output example.  2. You want to blame Python but ask for help from people who appreciate Python? 3. No, Python and its re library does not have a special problem with the } character -- you are doing it wrong.  4. This is obviously homework; you should add the "homework" tag to your question.

Comment: When I was in college, my algorithms professor had a strict policy: if you came to his office asking for help without examples of what you had already tried we would tell students to get out. In that same vein: get out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the very end of your program:

```
    # print allWords[i][j],
    print a,
```

the output becomes:

```
import sys  

n = int(sys.argv[1]) 
print "Beginning of the program!"

for i in range(1,n) :
   print "The number:"
   print i

if n < 5 :
   print n 
   print "less than 5"
```

Looks pretty close to what you want.  To output to an open file object `g`, instead of stdout, just another tiny change at the program's very end...:

```
    # print allWords[i][j],
    print>>g, a,
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I changed the end of the program as you said and added the following to the beginning:

import sys
name = str(sys.argv[1])
f = open(name, 'r')

and now it uses paramter. Thanks again.

Comment: @fema, you're welcome!  (I forgot I also had to edit the txt file to say CICKLUS instead of LOOP &c, but I imagine that was an obviously accidental "half translation" on your part, i.e. you had just translated the words in the txt file but not in the code).

Comment: yes, I forgot to translate that word when I copied the text, sorry

Answer (score 1):

A quick go at the problem (if you use it for homework make sure you understand what's going on; following a good Python language tutorial may help):

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]

replace_dict = { ";;": "\n", "LOOP": "for", "BRANCH": "if", "{": ":{" }
indent_dict = { "{": 1, "}": -1, "\n": 0 }

lines = open(filename).readlines()
indent, output, pop_next_newline = 0, [], False

for line in lines:
    for key, value in replace_dict.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(key, value)
    for char in line:
        if char in indent_dict:
            indent += indent_dict[char]
            if pop_next_newline and char == "\n":
                pop_next_newline = False
            else:
                output.append("\n%s" % ("    " * indent))
            if char == "}": 
                pop_next_newline = True
        else:
            output.append(char)

print ''.join(output)
```